# How can I calculate the average run up of all of the trades that my strategy?

Tags: pine-script

I have a pinescript startegy that I want to calculate the average run-up which is what was the highest price it could have sold for.
I know that the code goes something like - strategy.closedtrades.max_runup().
I'm not sure how to apply it to all trades and not just one specific trade and I also don't know where the output is displayed.
If someone could help me that would be great.

I have tried inputting the strategy.closedtrades.max_runup() code but im not sure how to work it or where anything is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
strategy.max_runup
```

which is the Maximum equity run-up value for the whole trading interval.

Comment: where is that plotted? or like where can I see it?

Comment: @ZachOwens it is not plotted it is a value accessible in pinescript